# Is it correct to say $\left| \iint_R dA \right|= \iint_R dA$ for an arbitary region $R$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Is it correct to say that $$\left| \iint_R dA \right|= \iint_R dA$$ for an arbirtary region in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I am trying to derive the formula for the curl operator, and on Wikipedia it is defined as

> $$\operatorname{curl}(\vec{F}) \cdot \hat {n}= \lim \limits_{A \to 0} \dfrac{1}{|A|} \oint_{C} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}.$$

If I choose $\hat n= \hat k$ and $\vec{F}(x,y) = [P(x,y), Q(x,y), R(x,y)]$ and $E$ is the region enclosed by positively-oriented closed curve $C$, then by Green's theorem:

$$\operatorname{curl}(\vec{F}) \cdot \hat {n}= \lim \limits_{A \to 0} \dfrac{1}{|A|} \iint_E \left(\dfrac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{x}}-\dfrac{\partial{P}}{\partial{y}}\right) dA .$$

However, $A = \iint_E dA$, and if I could remove the absolute values somehow, mean value theorem would let me get the correct value for the z-component of the curl.

Comment: Oh I didn't even notice. I'll fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\iint_R dA=\operatorname{area}(R)\geq 0$$

Comment: Perfect! Just wanted to clarify